Convergence in comparison principles of parabolic pdes
I assume that the following equations all have sufficiently smooth strong solutions.
I have demonstrated that the solution to the (imaginary-time) Schrödinger equation:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{cases}
            \partial_t u = \Delta u - c(x)u, & (t,x) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}^n\\
            u(0,x) = u_0(x)
        \end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
can be expressed as the convolution of a kernel with $ u_0$, where $ u_0 $ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n $ and continuous almost everywhere, $c(x)$ is smooth and nonnegative(so that this parabolic equation satisfies the comparison principle or the maximum principle), by utilizing the Feymann-Kac formula. Therefore, the solution can be denoted as:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        u(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} K(t,x,y) u_0(y) \, dy \equiv e^{tH}u_0\equiv e^{tH_{\mathbb{R}^n}}u_0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $Hu:=\Delta u +c(x)u$ is the Schrödinger operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$
Furthermore, we consider the solution to the initial-boundary value problem:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \begin{cases}
            \partial_t u = \Delta u - c(x)u, & (t,x) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \Omega\\
            u(0,x) = u_0(x)\\
            u(t,x) = 0, & x \in \partial\Omega
        \end{cases}  
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $ \Omega$ is assumed to be a bounded convex domain with a smooth boundary. According to subsection 2.4.4 of Heat Kernel Method and its Applications, there exists a kernel function $ K_{\Omega}(t,x,y)$, such that the solution can be expressed as:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        u(t,x) = \int_{\Omega} K_{\Omega}(t,x,y) u_0(y) \, dy\equiv e^{tH_{\Omega}}u_0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
I want to know if the initial value problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be approximated by a sequence of initial-boundary value problems. Consider a sequence of bounded convex
smooth domains $\{\Omega_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that
$$\Omega_1\subset \Omega_2\subset\cdots \subset \Omega_n\subset \cdots,\;\; \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \Omega_n = \mathbb{R}^n$$
Let $u_n:=e^{tH_{\Omega_n}}(u_0\chi_{\Omega_n})$. Could $u_n(t,x)$ converge to $u(t,x):=e^{tH_{\mathbb{R}^n}}u_0$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and for any fixed $t>0$? It seems that this conjecture holds for $c(x)\equiv 0$(the heat equation) by Kazuhiro Ishige et al. in To Logconcavity and Beyond. They stated that for any $n=1,2,\cdots$, let $u_n:=e^{t\Delta_{\Omega_n}}(u_0\chi_{\Omega_n})$, then
\begin{align*}
    &u_n(t,x)\leqslant u_{n+1}(t,x)\leqslant u(t,x):=e^{t\Delta}u_0, \text{in }\Omega_n\times (0,\infty)\\
    &u(t,x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n(t,x)
    , \text{in }\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,\infty)
\end{align*}
where $e^{t\Delta_{\Omega_n}}$ is the heat semigroup in $\Omega_n$. But they do not give any proof. I could only prove that $u_n(t,x)\leqslant u_{n+1}(t,x)$ by the comparison principle, but I could not prove that $u(t,x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n(t,x)$. Additionally I am uncertain whether this conclusion holds for general second-order parabolic equations that satisfy the comparison principle. Could you kindly suggest any textbooks or papers where I might find a similar result? Thank you very much!
